# How to fix onedrive regularly stopping to download files

Tags: bash, sync

I have installed the onedrive package in my Ubuntu Server 20.04 environment. Now I want to do an initial download of all my OneDrive files (almost 1 TB) using

```
onedrive --synchronize --download-only -v &> /home/myuser/onedrive.log &
```

However, it regularly runs for just a few hours, then it just stops syncing without an error message. The log just doesn't show any progress anymore, although the server internet connection is still fine.

When I kill and restart it (using the same command), it resumes to download and everything is working fine for a few hours again. Since the download is pretty slow, it would take me very long to get the full copy needing to restart every now and then.

Any ideas what could be the reason for this and how to fix it?

*EDIT: An update to the current version as described in the accepted solution fixed the problem.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

> I have installed the onedrive package in my Ubuntu Server 20.04 environment.

What version did you install? What is the output of `onedrive --version`

Please note, installing the client from the Ubuntu repositories is not supported. Those repositories contain obsolete and outdated client versions.

To install the client correctly on *any* Ubuntu platform you *must* follow this document: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/ubuntu-package-install.md

If you want this process or position to change, someone from the Ubuntu community needs to become the package maintainer and keep the Ubuntu 'onedrive' package up-to-date.

> However, it regularly runs for just a few hours, then it just stops syncing without an error message.

It *sounds* like you are hitting this known issue: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/known-issues.md#application-stops-running-without-any-visible-reason

**Application 'stops' running without any visible reason**

When running the client and performing an upload or download operation, the application just stops working without any reason or explanation. If `echo $?` is used after the application has exited without visible reason, an error level of 141 may be provided.

Additionally, this issue has mainly been seen when the client is operating against Microsoft's Europe Data Centre's.

**Explanation:**

The client is heavily dependent on Curl and OpenSSL to perform the activities with the Microsoft OneDrive service. Generally, when this issue occurs, the following is found in the HTTPS Debug Log: `OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104`

The only way to determine that this is the cause of the application ceasing to work is to generate a HTTPS debug log using the following additional flags: `--verbose --verbose --debug-https`

Additionally in the future, please post your questions or issue using the client on the GitHub site so that they can be tracked better & responded to in a timely fashion.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your development and your information about the potential problems. I checked the version installed with Ubuntu and it is v2.4.13-1build1, so it's slightly outdated as you suspected. I restartet onedrive with the verbose and debug parameters and will check the log the next time onedrive stops syncing. I will also consider an update as per your description after that analysis.

Comment: v2.4.13 was released Jul 14, 2021 - so you are running a very very very old and obsolete version, that will also contain some highly critical bugs that have been fixed. Please review https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/releases for details.

Regardless of your analysis - please upgrade your client urgently.

Comment: I will try the update. With the old version the sync stopped with the following message in debug mode:
* Too old connection (126 seconds idle), disconnect it
* Connection 3 seems to be dead!
* Closing connection 3